# Changing the value of a property from inside a function (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way I can define a property in a class and then change the value of the property from inside a function?

I want to do this so that if I click a button in my template, then the value of this boolean property changes.

For example:

```js
export class ClassName {
   trueOrFalse: boolean = false;

   changeBooleanValue() {
      //How do I change the value of trueOrFalse from inside the function
      this.trueOrFalse = true; //The value of trueOrFalse is true only within the scope of the function
   } 
}
```

So, in my HTML view, if I click a button,the value of the boolean property should change from `false` to `true`.

```html
<button (click)="changeBooleanValue()"></button>
```

I'm new to Angular (and programming in general), so if there is anything I can read and learn the basics from, that would be helpful.

Comment: No, once you changed it, it will be true.
Your using "this" which means this class and its attributes.

Comment: simply add parentheses: `<button (click)="changeBooleanValue()"></button>`. this should do the trick

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the parenthesis while writing the question down. I did use it in the code. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @sharanyaam The variable assigned to `true` and working well after you added the parenthesis.

Comment: @Talg123 It works. If I put a console.log(this.trueOrFalse) just above the function, I get errors like "; expected" or " , expected". I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be having an issue with the scope of your 'this' pointer, which can depend on how the method is called.

Try changing your method to a function, e.g.

```
export class ClassName {
   trueOrFalse: boolean = false;

   changeBooleanValue = () => {
      this.trueOrFalse = true; 
   }
}
```

This will ensure that the function is bound to it's parent object.

Comment: I have an additional question - 
If I put console.log(this.trueOrFalse) just above the function, I get errors like " ';' expected" or "  ',' expected". I don't understand why.

Comment: That's because you're not putting the code in a function or a method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some other error in your code, Your snippet works without any issues.
Check this [sackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xphsa3) based on your code snippet